# The meaning of notation $\subset\subset$ in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, notation

I have read the book Function Theory of Several Complex Variables of Krantz. But there is a notation the meaning of which I don't know. The notation is $\subset\subset$. For example, "let $\Omega\subset\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a connected open set".

Can somebody give me a definition?

Comment: As Zhen says, this notation usually means $\Omega$ is relatively compact in $R^n$. Why analysts tend to prefer this notation to saying "relatively compact in" or simply "bounded" if $R^n$ is involved will always remain a mystery to me...

Comment: Is $\subset\subset$ the same as  ⋐ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an index of notation at [the back of the book](http://books.google.com/books?id=uZZsh1w_RJcC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA510#v=onepage&q&f=false). Apparently, $\subset \subset$ means ‘relatively compact in’ and is defined in section 1.1.

Comment: I have checked the index of notation of the book,but I don't find it.I just need some conclusions from this book,so I don't read this book carefully.Thank you for your help.