# What does the symbol $\Subset$ mean?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, notation

> It always possible to shrink a domain $U_\alpha$ to $V_\alpha$ in the sense that $$V_\alpha\Subset U_\alpha\quad\text{and} \quad\bigcup_{\alpha}U_\alpha=\bigcup_{\alpha}V_\alpha\,?$$

What does $\Subset$ mean ? Is it an error ?

Comment: @NormalHuman: My question is only on the sense of $\Subset$. What other tag can be used excepted "Notation" ?

Comment: Notation is context-dependent. Presumably this has to do with topology or analysis?

Comment: These seem to be relevant:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43950/meaning-of-subset-notation
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56872/the-meaning-of-a-notation-from-complex-analysis

Comment: You could tell us in what source you found the notation. Have you checked that the author did not define the notation?

Comment: ^ same thing with  less fancy typography.

Answer (score 3):

According to my Differential Geometry professor, it means that the closure of $V_{\alpha}$ is contained in $U_{\alpha}$.

According to Silvia Ghinassi and other sources, it generally means that the closure of $V_{\alpha}$ is a compact subset of $U_{\alpha}$, in which case the notation $V_{\alpha}\Subset U_{\alpha}$ is read "$V_{\alpha}$ is compactly contained in $U_{\alpha}$".

Comment: This is called being "compactly contained". It generally means that the closure of $V_{\alpha}$ is a compact subset of $U_{\alpha}$.

Comment: Yes, I read about this more restrictive definition. I will edit my answer. Thank you.