# If $f\in C(U)$, then $f^{\epsilon }\to f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $U$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

If $f\in C(U)$, then $f^{\epsilon }\to f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $U$
[image]

[image]

my Question how he says that $f$ is uniformly on $W$ i am so learner and the only hope i learn sobolev spaces is MATHSSTACK....... so thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

$W$ is contained in a compact contained in $U$ (see [The meaning of notation $\subset\subset$ in complex analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56872/the-meaning-of-notation-subset-subset-in-complex-analysis)).
 And continuous in a compact implies uniformly continuous...